# XML too big to parse

Tags: ios, xml

I have an 170 MB XML file in my server, and I need to get some information from that file, but I don´t know how to read such a big file. I am trying with common methods, but I need to know which is the best method.

What is the most efficient way to parse big XML files?

Comment: Use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is parsing the xml,since your XML file is so big, you should look at using a SAX parser. Here is a helpful link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project